# How to be notified on network status change?

Tags: java, network-programming

my application, written in Java, need to get notified each time internet connection is re-established after it is lost.

Comment: @om-nom-nom Did you find something? :) Because I've endup writing simple notification lib about config changes (it was easy) but then I'm using java api (java.net.NetworkInterface) to examine configuration and its really tricky. Impl of this API have several bugs, so I would prefer to have native lib wrapped to java to do so...

Comment: @tuxSlayer I'm not the one who asked the question ;) ask OP (Massimo Fazzolari)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is very platform specific. Depending on your operating system, you have to evaluate the possibilities for acess to networking interfaces and how to be notified about changes. Since I don't know a ready-to-use library to accomplish these kind of things, you might end up writing native, platform-dependent and perhaps low-level code yourself and invoking it from the JVM for instance via JNA or JNI.